# AX - How to flush Macro from cache

Tags: macros, axapta, flush, ax

It seems AX Macro remains in cache

I had a macro defined in AOT and declared in classDeclaration

as I needed to change one of the values
I want to force all users to get the new value when they reopen AX
but **user is still getting the old value of a Macro**

*Macro definition: TestMacro*

```
#define.columnA(1)
//#define.columnC(3)    // old value
#define.columnC(2)      // new value
```

*Class Declaration: TestClass*

```
class TestClass
{
    #TestMacro  // Remove/save and re-add/save this declaration apparently solved
}
```

### Attempted Solutions:

1. Deleting Usage Data related to TestClass (for all users): **Failed**
2. Removing and re-adding Macro from class declaration: **Worked**

Some other idea how to flush macro cache in AX?

Comment: What I meant by "cache" is the concept of storaging any value for reuse it in the future in this or any other session, from memory, from table, file or whatever and wherever it may be kept. Recompiling the caller in order to retrieve any new value from the referenced macro is not working for me.

Comment: In case of AX 2012 you should dó an incremental CIL as well. Doing both *will* solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Jan B., thanks for replying. Unfortunately incremental CIL is not working for me. I tested on AX 2012 R3.

Comment: If incremental is not working, then do a full. If that is not working, fix your compile errors.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no cache specifically for macros, but an object cache that caches all AOT objects. You can flush this cache using **Tools > Development tools > Application objects > Refresh Dictionary/AOD**.

But your problem is not this object cache, but the compiled version of `TestClass`. During compilation the reference to `TestMacro` is replaced with the actual macro values. So even if you change the `TestMacro`, the compiled version of `TestClass` will still run with the old macro values. You have to recompile `TestClass` so that it will consider the changes in `TestMacro`.

In case your macro values are changing regularly, you should consider using a parameter table instead of a macro.

Comment: Hi FH! Thanks for answering. You are right, what I am looking for is the trigger to retrieve new value for a macro. then erase all is not my solution, neither changing more than ten classes from constants (macro values) to parameter table as it was designed to make deployment of constants easier between environments and avoid rework on setup. Unfortunatelly, the theory "...recompile TestClass so that it will consider the changes in TestMacro." is not working.

Comment: This is not a theory, I tested this in a AX 2012 R2 CU7 system and [it works](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=37190D098C7D2D3B&resid=37190D098C7D2D3B%211098&authkey=AEYxgZSka-IRDjM).

Comment: FH, I just tested on AX 2012 R3 and it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Macros are cached but are replaced during compile.  Are you compiling only the method and not the entire class?